# HiveQL select not working as expected on an external table with partitions

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm facing an issue when I use select statement on a custom external table that I have created. I have added partitions to this table after creating the table for year month and day using the add partition command.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm getting only one row where day = 1 for this select statement where I'm expecting 5 rows for 5 days.

```
select * from test_data where key = 'AX001';
```

For each of these statements I'm getting one result.

```
select * from test_data where key = 'AX001' and day = 2;
select * from test_data where key = 'AX001' and day = 3;
```

But for this I'm getting only one row with day = 2.

```
select * from test_data where key = 'AX001' and day in (2,3);
```

Any idea what might be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: What version of Hive? *(lots of bugs coming and going on each release...)* Did you actually define `DAY` as String or Integer? What happens when you replace `and DAY in (2,3)` with `and (DAY =2 or DAY =3)`?

Comment: Hive 0.13.1-CDH5.2.0..I defined day as int in the create table statement "partitioned by ( year int, month int, day int)".. and (day=2 or day=3) also gives me one row with day =2. I just tried day in (3,4,5) and got a row where day =3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly the solution here [Hive MapReduce job splitting up files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296525/hive-mapreduce-job-splitting-up-files), which was another issue that I was has having solved this

```
select * from test_table where key = 'AX001' and day in (1,2,3);

set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat; 
select * from test_table where key = 'AX001' and day in (1,2,3);

set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;
select * from test_table where key = 'AX001' and day in (1,2,3);
```

Only the last one gives me 3 results.The first two just returns two rows.